# Accessing a Dropdown from child window

Tags: asp.net

I have on server control(dropdown) and One button.user can select some values in dropdown and click button.I have to show a pop-up.In this pop-up I have show data based upon value selected in dropdown.How to access a dropdown in codebehind of pop-up screen.I am loading a .aspx in pop-up using javascript.

Comment: You wanted to access the value of the drop down with server side code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just pass the selected value of the dropdownlist as a querystring parameter to the popup page?

That's the way i'd do it.

If you dont want to do it that way, you can access the parent window by using  `window.opener.document`.

So something like:

```
window.opener.document.getElementById('yourDDLId').value;
```

Still i'd recommend passing through as querystring param. Simple and easy.